# Import test data to theme?

Tags: 8

I'm quite new to Drupal, and I'm still in learning process. I've installed a pure Drupal 8, and installed a the [YG Agency](https://www.drupal.org/project/yg_agency) theme. Right now the theme is only blank. Is it possible to load some test data into the theme, as it is displayed in the Demo?

http://demo.drupalfreethemes.com/drupal/free-themes/yg_agency/

I know this can be done is many WordPress themes? Does Drupal support importing test data to themes as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be asked on https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/yg_agency?categories=All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The YG Agency theme has a link to the prepopulated database from the following page:

https://www.drupal.org/project/yg_agency

Just click on the link that says "Download Demo Site".

You can then import the database into MySQL or the like.

Comment: Could you share me link download demo site? I can not download from origin site. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure? The link in the homepage is working for me: https://demo.drupalfreethemes.com/drupal/free-themes-html/yg-agency/

Comment: Yes, The site can not send link download to my email. https://www.drupaldevelopersstudio.com/free-drupal-themes/yg-agency. I'm still waiting for email.